# Trouble with iOS UI Automation Accessing tableView Elements

Tags: ios, uiview, automation

My View Hierarchy is as follows:

```
UIAWindow "(null)" {{0, 0}, {1024, 768}}
UIATableView "Sample Table" {{645, 138}, {308, 437}}
elements: {
         UIATableCell "Sample Cell" {{645, 182}, {308, 44}}
         elements: {
                 UIAStaticText "Sample Cell" {{645, 182}, {308, 44}}
         }
```

I have tried the following queries to tap the "Sample Cell" as follows:

```
app.mainWindow().tableViews()["Sample Table"].tableCells()["Sample Cell"].tap();
app.mainWindow().tableViews()["Sample Table"].staticTexts()["Sample Cell"].tap();
app.mainWindow().tableViews()["Sample Table"].tableCells()["Sample Cell"].staticTexts()["Sample Cell"].tap();
```

All my attempts result with the error:

```
Cannot perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil
```

Am I misunderstanding on how you are suppose to drill into table elements?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not understand that to access tableCells in a tableView you call "cells".

So correct functioning query is:

```
 app.mainWindow().tableViews()["Sample Table"].cells()["Sample Cell"].tap();
```